# batch file for looping a folder and copy and then renaming

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Basically what I want to achieve is to copy all files in that directory and pasting it with new in the name in the same directory so
`2ic.mdl` to `new2ic.mdl`

code:

```
for f in ../models/model/vehicle/train/* DO 
(
copy $f  ../models/model/vehicle/train/$new{f}
)
```

but because of the loop I don't even get a error it just closes
and I need to do that for a lot of different folders
all my effort to fix it didn't work out so far
and that i don't see the copy error doas imply my for loop is already flawed

for /r  .\models\model\vehicle\train\  %%name in (.) do (

echo test
pause
echo copy $f  ..\models\model\vehicle\train$new{f}
)

echo ende
pause

Comment: This isn't batch syntax. Which language do you use?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Meki. The `batch-file` and `cmd` tags are for Microsoft DOS and Windows products. Use the command `FOR /?` to see the correct syntax for a `FOR` loop. If you are not using a Microsoft OS, then please choose different tags.

Comment: its supposed to be batch     for /? is nice

Comment: so for /r   %%name in ( ../models/model/vehicle/train/) do  
is this correct?

Comment: Almost, you need to be sure that you use `do (`. An opening parenthesis must be on the same line as the `Do` instruction, with a space separating them.

Comment: for /r  .\models\model\vehicle\train\  %%name in (.) do (


echo test
pause
copy $f  ..\models\model\vehicle\train\$new{f}
)

this what i have so far but it still dosent get to the echo test pause so something is still wrong

Comment: `$f` and `$new{f}` isn't batch syntax. I think you want `ECHO copy "%%~ff" " %%~dpf\new%%~nxf"`. The `ECHO` is to just show the command on the screen without really executing it. Remove it after troubleshooting, when you are sure it does what you want. See `for /?` (again) for what `%%~ff`, `%%~dpf`, and `%%~nxf` are doing.

Comment: atlest the loop seams to work now. (*) and the %% variable has to be single character only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /r  .\models\model\vehicle\train\  %%i in (*) do (
&:: for each file in path. make i the path+file  D:\..train\bigboy.exe

copy "%%i" "%%~dpi\new%%~nxi"
&::%%~dpi takes the path from i 
&::%%~nxi takes the old file name and ending 
echo done
pause 
)
echo ende
pause
```

so in case i or someone else need this i tryed my best to explain every operation
because that did hurt my own Research on this platform